# Should I flag my own question for migration to another site?

Tags: discussion

I recently asked a question about whether there is a [trick to divide a constant (power of two) by an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35063224/3581917).  Several people have added some really useful comments that have steered my research in a mathematical direction.  Now I'm wondering whether the question would be a better fit for the [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) community.

Not knowing much about mathematics, how do I determine whether my question is a good fit for their community?

If it is a good fit, how do I determine whether to migrate it or post a new question there which is more theoretical and less software oriented?

Comment: 1. You could read their help center, post in their meta or ask in their chat. 2. As you don't have answers, you can just delete and post again on the new site rather than formally migrating.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks.  I've posted a new question there, after guidance on their chat, and now await a torrent of down-votes for being a maths n00b.  I'll leave my question open on here for now, and maybe answer it (citing Math SE) if anything does turn up there.  There's always a good chance that someone here may still be able to answer.

Comment: Cross-posting is discouraged, please remove one.